# How to grep strings that matches two (or more) variables in R

Tags: r, regex, list

I have a list from which I would like to extract specific elements to put into a new list e.g.

```
   MyFullList = (
  "
  'BLUEh473vs65hRED7vfd8edgf9GLOSS.csv', 
  'BLUE5654vsy56hgfREDjkgr7MATTE.csv', 
  'BLUEhjirhgccsREDgfigjINCAN.csv', 
  'BLUEvfdjhkldfgsGREENdfggh5GLOSS.csv', 
  'BLUEtgergvsGREENsghjkhgnMATTE.csv',
  'BLUEjgh4gvsGREENjkhgfdINCAN.csv',

  ....

  'GREENhfuewhvsBLUEhfsMATTE.csv'
  'GREENkdfgvsBLUEfjhINCAN.csv'
"

)
```

If I only wanted to extract files that began with Blue but then contained both the words Green and Matte, how would I do this?

Currently, I have managed to adapt this from someone else but I cannot manipulate it further:

```
MySelection <- MyFullList[grep("^(?=[^BLUE])(?=.*MATTE)", names(MyFullList), value = T, perl=T)]
```

Which just seems to return anything ending containing matte.

I've also tried things such as:

```
MySelection <- MyFullList[grep("^BLUE|GREEN|MATTE.csv$"), names(MyFullList), value = T]
```

Which I believe is having the same effect.

And my attempts to use an asterisk:

```
MySelection <- MyFullList[grep("^BLUE.*GREEN.*MATTE.csv$"), names(MyFullList), value = T]
```

seem to be completely misguided as well.

Following on from that, How would I then use a variable in a Grep command?

e.g.

```
Colours=('BLUE', 'RED', 'GREEN')

for i in 1:length(Colours) {

    grep("^[[Colours[i]]].*GREEN.*MATTE.csv$"), names(MyFullList), value = T]
}
```

Comment: What does your data look like?!  Reason: `names(MyFullList)`

Comment: Just a note, the data is currently not a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue arising due to `\n`. An alternative would be to read the data first with `read.table`:

```
MyFullList = read.table(text=
  "
  'BLUEh473vs65hRED7vfd8edgf9GLOSS.csv', 
  'BLUE5654vsy56hgfREDjkgr7MATTE.csv', 
  'BLUEhjirhgccsREDgfigjINCAN.csv', 
  'BLUEvfdjhkldfgsGREENdfggh5GLOSS.csv', 
  'BLUEtgergvsGREENsghjkhgnMATTE.csv',
  'BLUEjgh4gvsGREENjkhgfdINCAN.csv',

  ....

  'GREENhfuewhvsBLUEhfsMATTE.csv'
  'GREENkdfgvsBLUEfjhINCAN.csv'
"

,as.is=T,header=F,fill=T)
mfl<-MyFullList[,-ncol(MyFullList)]
```

Then our result:

```
mfl[grep("^BLUE.*GREEN.*MATTE.csv$",mfl)]
[1] "BLUEtgergvsGREENsghjkhgnMATTE.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use three logical conditions like so:

```
x <- c("BLUEh473vs65hRED7vfd8edgf9GLOSS.csv", 
       "BLUE5654vsy56hgfREDjkgr7MATTE.csv",
       "BLUEhjirhgccsREDgfigjINCAN.csv",
       "BLUEvfdjhkldfgsGREENdfggh5GLOSS.csv",
       "BLUEtgergvsGREENsghjkhgnMATTE.csv",
       "BLUEjgh4gvsGREENjkhgfdINCAN.csv",
       "GREENhfuewhvsBLUEhfsMATTE.cs",
       "GREENkdfgvsBLUEfjhINCAN.csv")


x[grepl("^BLUE", x) & grepl("MATTE",x) & grepl("GREEN",x)]
[1] "BLUEtgergvsGREENsghjkhgnMATTE.csv"
```